# Prevent velocity from being increased by fixed joints

Tags: unity, c#, physics, joints

I am currently working on a Unity project that makes use of fixed joints. When connecting two GameObjects using a fixed joint, I noticed a behavior where the gameobject that becomes part of a fixed joint gets velocity added for a short time. The added velocity disappears after a fraction of a second.

[image]

I add the fixed joint as follows:

```
baseObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>().connectedBody = targetObject.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

Is there an explanation for this behavior and is it possible to prevent it?

EDIT:

The way I select the two objects is that I look at the objects and then listen on the KeyDown event, which then uses Raycast to determine the object to be connected. Once two objecte are selected the joint is added.

```
private float maxShootDistance = 40f;
private GameObject baseObject;
private GameObject targetObject;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
    {
        if (baseObject)
        {
            targetObject = SelectObject();
            if (targetObject)
            {
                JoinObjects();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            baseObject = SelectObject();
        }
    }
}

private void JoinObjects()
{
    baseObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>().connectedBody = targetObject.transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private GameObject SelectObject()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(GetComponentInParent<Camera>().transform.position, GetComponentInParent<Camera>().transform.forward, out RaycastHit hit, maxShootDistance)
        && hit.rigidbody != null)
    {
        return hit.collider.gameObject;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The GameObjects to be connected are two fresh created cubes to which a Rigitbody component is added.

[image]
[image]

The described behavior rarely causes the connected gameobjects to start moving in the scene. Most likely because the velocity disappears very quickly. However, you can reliably observe this by opening the info of the Rigitbody of an object and looking at it while adding the joint. From the same info comes the first image of the question.

Comment: How are you configuring the anchors, dictating which points of each object should be bolted together and in what orientation? It's possible that the objects' initial configuration at the time of connection does not match this, and the physics engine is applying an impulse to snap the objects into the alignment enforced by the joint.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. This sounds promising as I currently do not configure an anchor when creating the joint. In this case, do I need to add the selected point on the targetObjects to the joint.anchor in the baseObject? I am undecided on this as I have not seen a use case for this yet. Is there an example for this case?

Comment: I'm not sure, just speculating. If you can edit your question to show us a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example that demonstrates the problem, we can try various interventions and test what works.

Comment: Sure! I added an complete verifiable example to the question.

Comment: In order for this example to be complete, we also need to know what objects with what components to put in our scene, and where, and if/how they move.

Comment: all right, I have added